# How to append locally processed data via shinyapp to local file?

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if anyone had ideas on how to use a shinyapp to analyze new files and append the output to an existing one.

I am designing a shinyapp that will perform a series of QA/QC checks and gather summaries on certain parameters. The input are files from a lab instrument, and I want to take a file, analyze it, and then append the output to an existing file that serves as a central source for all the analyzed instrument data. All of this, including running the app, will be done locally (the files and their destination after processing are on the same PC) and not via any web hosting service like shinyapps.io.

Any ideas on how to do this would be awesome. I want to use shinyapps because it can create an accessible workflow for someone unfamiliar with R, but I am having trouble escaping the apps self contained "reactivity".

Comment: Allowing a shiny app to have write access to a file on the filesystem is a significant security risk. I suggest another alternative (that is safer and might be more performant) is to use a database of sorts, even if as simple as SQLite or DuckDB (both are file-based, not "big server" databases). Since you're working with shinyapps.io, though, you'll need to find a way to store it in a way that updates to your app do not overwrite the database file; I don't use shinyapps so I cannot advise there, sorry.